# How can get font wordpad whit python win32

Tags: python, winapi, fonts, notepad, wordpad

How do I find the current Word Pad application with Python and win32gui fonts?
I was able to find Windows Handler and the child windows
A sample application is below

```py
import win32gui,win32api,win32con,win32ui

hwnd = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()
dc = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwnd)
hfont = win32gui.SendMessage(dc, win32con.WM_GETFONT, 0,0)
fnt_spc = {}
fnt_n = win32ui.CreateFont(fnt_spc)
lf = win32gui.SelectObject(hfont,fnt_n.GetSafeHandle())
print(lf.lfFaceName)
```

Comment: The control in WordPad is a Rich Edit, According to the [Unsupported Edit Control Functionality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/about-rich-edit-controls#unsupported-edit-control-functionality): [`EM_GETCHARFORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-getcharformat) should be used instead of `WM_GETFONT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the Spy++, the control in WordPad is Rich Edit:
[image]

According to the [Unsupported Edit Control Functionality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/about-rich-edit-controls#unsupported-edit-control-functionality): [`EM_GETCHARFORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-getcharformat) should be used instead of `WM_GETFONT`.

First, you need to get the Rich Edit handle(with Spy++ directly,or `WindowFromPoint`, `FindWindowEx`, `EnumChildWindows`and etc. But `GetDesktopWindow` you used will just return a handle to the desktop window, and `SendMessage` receive a window handle but not a device context handle)

In addition, you still need to note that when sending `EM_GETCHARFORMAT` message in another process, you need to request a piece of memory for reading and writing a [`CHARFORMAT2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/richedit/ns-richedit-charformat2a_1) structure in the window process to interact with the two processes.

C++ Sample(remove the error checking):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Richedit.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    HWND hwnd = (HWND)0x00090BF0;
    DWORD pid = 0;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd,&pid);
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_OPERATION| PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_VM_WRITE,false, pid);//7784
    CHARFORMAT2 cp;
    cp.cbSize = sizeof(CHARFORMAT2);
    cp.dwMask = CFM_FACE;
    CHARFORMAT2* lf = (CHARFORMAT2*)VirtualAllocEx(hProcess,NULL,sizeof(CHARFORMAT2), MEM_COMMIT|MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    BOOL ret = WriteProcessMemory(hProcess,lf,&cp, sizeof(CHARFORMAT2),NULL);
    //ZeroMemory(&lf,sizeof(lf));

    LRESULT lr = SendMessage(hwnd, EM_GETCHARFORMAT, SCF_SELECTION, (LPARAM)lf);

    ret = ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, lf, &cp, sizeof(CHARFORMAT2), NULL);
    std::cout << cp.szFaceName << std::endl;
    VirtualFreeEx(hProcess,lf, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

> Courier New

Comment: Hi, did this help to you? Please fee free to let me know if you have any issues.